# Is too many cookies bad?

Tags: php, html, cookies, web

So currently I have one cookie set, (its for the theme of my website) and the start of my php gets the cookie then I have a really long switch case that sets everything according to the cookie I got.

Would it be bad if I just set like 10 different cookies and loaded the cookies? Or would the way I currently have it not that bad?

Currently have it: http://pastebin.com/dJP6Fz5R

I'm just going over my code and I realize that every time my page is loaded it sets everything and goes through the switch case. So I could make a cookie for every one and load the data that way. But is getting the user's cookie values take just as much time as a switch case?

Would one be faster/more efficient then the other? Or are they both about the same.

Any information would be awesome, thank you.

Comment: Yes, eating too many cookies will give you a stomach ache.

Comment: Efficiency is not an issue. But you could simplify your code with an array map instead of the lengthy switch.

Comment: I think this solution is good. maybe you should export the theme-setups into own php files and include them only for better overview.

Comment: You could save the theme options (base on the cookie color) in a session. And perhaps you can reduce this by providing different stylesheets which you then add to the head of your document. Anyway, your solution does not take long to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about what you want would be just include a stylesheet conditionally. E.g.

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['theme'])){
   switch($color_recieved){
       case 'gray(default)':
           setcookie('theme', 'gray', time()+60*60*24, '/', '.example.com');
       break;
       // ...etc
   }
}

$theme = '<link src="/css/themes/'.$_COOKIE['theme'].'.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />';
```

Create stylesheets with theme-specific styles, then in your html header echo `$theme`.

Comment: Changes of the theme will never get to already cookied users, imho kinda bad idea to store the complete data at the user.

Answer (score 3):

Too many cookies can make any web app obese :)

But you shouldn't worry in this case, unless a meg of cookies, no efficiency you otherwise could have had will be lost